# Passing Enums as parameter from abstract class

Tags: c#, enums

I have an abstract base class, `TestFactory` which looks like:

```
    public abstract class TestFactory
    {
        //static method that can create concrete factories
        public static TestFactory CreateTestFactory(FactoryType factoryType)
        {
            TestFactory factory = null;
            switch (factoryType)
            {
                case FactoryType.Blood:
                    factory = new BloodTestFactory();
                    break;
                case FactoryType.Urine:
                    factory = new UrineTestFactory();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return factory;
        }
        //BloodTestFactory and UrineTestFactory are concrete types 
        //that will need to create their own tests
        //this enum parameter needs to 'switch' between
        //BloodTestType and UrineTestType
        public abstract LabTest CreateTest(Enum e);
    }
    public enum FactoryType
    {
        Blood,Urine
    }
```

So this class creates a concrete factory like:

```
    public class BloodTestFactory :TestFactory
    {

        //both BloodTestFactory and UrineTestFactory will create a LabTest object
        //I would like to have a BloodTestType and UrineTestType enum, what do I need 
        //to do to pass a generic Enum as a parameter and then switch on BloodTestType

        public override LabTest CreateTest(Enum e)
        {
            BloodTest bt = null;
            //switch (e)
            //{
            //    default:
            //        break;
            //}
            //creation logic here
        }
    }
    public enum BloodTestType
    {
        H1AC,Glucose
    }
```

A `BloodTest` itself is an abstract class which will return a concrete `BloodTest` object based on the Enum value.  For clarity's sake I would like to have a `BloodTestType` and a `UrineTestType` (not shown) enum.  Since the `CreateTest` method is abstract, how can I make sure that I can pass it a `BloodTestType` when I want to create `BloodTest`s and a `UrineTestType` enum when I want to create UrineTest?

Comment: Can't you just convert your generic ``Enum e`` into a concrete ``BloodTestType`` inside your ``CreateTest`` method?

Comment: @Silvermind that would be simplest thing to do.  I was just curious if there was a more 'elegant' way to do it.  I know enums don't do inheritance, but I thought there might be some way around that.  Not that you could have known, but in reality the last of enums that could be needed could be quite large.

Comment: The more I look at this question the more I think your architecture is just wrong. You're trying to do a switch on an enum to determine what sort of test to do, but the whole point of patterns like Factory method/abstract factory is to remove such branching logic from your code. So you would end up with classes `GlucoseBloodLabTest`, `H1ACBloodLabTest`, `SomeUrineLabTest` etc. all inheriting from a base class `LabTest`. If you want to know how to change your code to do it another way post here and i'll work on a separate answer for you.

Comment: @Jamiec I believe I failed to illustrate it well enough, but in my design I had `BloodTest` as abstract as well.  So an abstract factory creates a factory, and BloodTestFactory can create any one of several abstract BloodTest types.  I do agree, though, that my design does not seem ideal.

Comment: @Jamiec I'm always in knowledge-seeking mode, and I would greatly appreciate any conference of knowledge :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>I'm not sure if this is the best approach to take for this requirement, I'll leave the design pattern discussion for comments / other answers.</sub>

I wouldn't necessarily do it this way, however, to make the code you have work, I would introduce a class level generic parameter on `TestFactory` for the `enum`.

```
public abstract class TestFactory<TTestType>
{
    public abstract LabTest CreateTest(TTestType testType);
}
```

Derived classes then simply specify the generic argument:

```
public class BloodTestFactory : TestFactory<BloodTestType>
{
    public override LabTest CreateTest(BloodTestType e)
    {
    }
}
```

Note that unless you use something like [Unconstrained Melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) you don't get much support for generic type constraints on `enum`.

Also note that this now makes it difficult to reference the shared base class because you need to close the generic argument:

```
TestFactory baseReference = myBloodTestFactory; // Not possible.

TestFactory<BloodTestType> baseReference = myBloodTestFactory;
```

Personally I'd likely decompose these two factories into separated classes without a base, or look into using an interface. Dealing with specific parameters in what you would like to have as "common" methods is difficult.

Comment: This *sort of* works, except the `CreateTestFactory` method now needs to take the generic type too, negating the use of `FactoryType`.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes that method needs to return a `TestFactory<T>`, like you say, this then starts to make the approach moot.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Not sure really. I would review the need for a base class at the moment. The method you want to have exposed by the base class has to take derived-class specific arguments, which to me defeats the need for it.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I would tend to agree with you.  :)

Comment: @Jamiec I've always found it difficult to reach a common approach on handling what you feel are logically related entities, but happen to need entity-specific method parameters (as in this case). What are your thoughts on an approach for it?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I'm a novice programmer, but determined person and when I come across a problem like this I feel sometimes it's cheating the process of learning if I don't hammer out something working.  The great thing about SO is being able to converse with people like yourself to get a academic AND real-world spin on things, which is nice.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, I'll mark it and see if @Jamiec comes back with anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice way of doing this, and it results in code such as:

```
var client = new LabTestClient();
client.Run<BloodTestFactory,BloodTestType>(BloodTestType.H1AC);
client.Run<BloodTestFactory,BloodTestType>(BloodTestType.Glucose);
// outputs
//   BloodTest: H1AC
//   BloodTest: Glucose
```

Here is the rest of the code, hopefully its quite self explanatory how to use it/extend it to your needs - there are concrete classes for each type of lab test.

First the client and the abstract classes

```
public class LabTestClient
{        
    public void Run<TFactory, TInput>(TInput input) where TFactory : LabTestFactory, new()
    {
        LabTestFactory factory = new TFactory();;
        LabTest labTest = factory.CreateLabTest();
        labTest.Run(input);
    }

}

public abstract class LabTest
{        
    public abstract void Run<TInput>(TInput input);
}

public abstract class LabTestFactory
{
    public abstract LabTest CreateLabTest();
}
```

Then the concrete implementation:

```
public enum BloodTestType{ H1AC,Glucose }

public class BloodTest: LabTest
{        
    public override void Run<TInput>(TInput input) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BloodTest: {0}",input);            
    }
}

public class BloodTestFactory : LabTestFactory
{
    public override LabTest CreateLabTest()
    {
        return new BloodTest();
    }
}

public enum UrineTestType{ A,B }

public class UrineTest: LabTest
{        
    public override void Run<TInput>(TInput input) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UrineTest: {0}",input);            
    }
}

public class UrineTestFactory : LabTestFactory
{
    public override LabTest CreateLabTest()
    {
        return new UrineTest();
    }
}
```

A live example: http://rextester.com/MUV89315

However, this is still not ideal, as the individual tests still don't enforce their input - and in fact when you come to do anything complex within the test you'll find you don't know what the actual type of `TInput` is unless you cast it to the right enum:

```
public class UrineTest: LabTest
{        
    public override void Run<TInput>(TInput input) 
    {
        var urineTestType = (UrineTestType)input;
        // do something useful.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be honest, this is a little outside of my pay grade! :)  Very grateful for the chance to learn.  Could you explain the `where TFactory : LabTestFactory, new()` part?

Comment: `where TFactory : LabTestFactory, new()` - a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) indicating the generic type must inherit `LabTestFactory` and must have a parameterless constructor (allows the type to itself behave like a factory - see in the method `new TFactory()`)

Answer (score 0):

Just test for type safety in your overriden method:

```
        public override LabTest CreateTest(Enum e)
        {
            BloodTest bt = null;
            if(!e.GetType.Equals(typeof(BloodTestType)))
            {
               // throw type exception of your choice
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an argument check to your base class:

```
public abstract class TestFactory
{
    //static method that can create concrete factories
    public static TestFactory CreateTestFactory(FactoryType factoryType)
    {
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(FactoryType), factoryType)
        {
             throw InvalidEnumArgumentException(...);
        }

        TestFactory factory = null;
        switch (factoryType)
        {
            case FactoryType.Blood:
                factory = new BloodTestFactory();
                break;
            case FactoryType.Urine:
                factory = new UrineTestFactory();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return factory;
    }       
    //...
}
```